# malloc error - incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsdata

I'm trying to get sub data of NSData object and at the same time multiple bytes by some value for my personal need  .

actually this affect the volume of .wav sound file .

but i get after few calls to the following function a malloc error at the malloc statement .

```
+(NSData *) subDataOfData: (NSData *) mainData withRange:(NSRange) range volume (CGFloat) volume
{
    // here is the problematic line:
    Byte * soundWithVolumeBytes = (Byte*)malloc(range.length); 
    Byte * mainSoundFileBytes =(Byte *)[mainData bytes];

    for (int i=range.location ; i< range.location + range.length; i=i+2)
    {
        // get the original sample
        int16_t sampleInt16Value = 0;
        sampleInt16Value = (sampleInt16Value<<8) + mainSoundFileBytes[i+1];
        sampleInt16Value = (sampleInt16Value<<8) + mainSoundFileBytes[i];

        //multiple sample 
        sampleInt16Value*=volume;

        //store the sample
        soundWithVolumeBytes[i] = (Byte)sampleInt16Value;
        soundWithVolumeBytes[i+1] =(Byte) (sampleInt16Value>>8);

    }


    NSData * soundDataWithVolume = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:soundWithVolumeBytes length:range.length];
    free(soundWithVolumeBytes);

    return [soundDataWithVolume autorelease];

}
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the value of `range.location` is non-zero, your `for` loop modifies locations beyond what's allocated. These lines

```
soundWithVolumeBytes[i] = ...
soundWithVolumeBytes[i+1] = ...
```

write to locations from `range.location` to `range.location+range.length-1`, but the allocated range is only from zero to `range.length`. You need to change the lines to

```
soundWithVolumeBytes[i-range.location] = ...
soundWithVolumeBytes[i+1-range.location] = ...
```

In addition, since you increment by two, the last iteration may access a byte past the end of the buffer in case the `range.location+range.length` is odd.